# Kafka Consumer InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am trying to create a kafka consumer which subscribe to a topic and poll regular interval.  Below @Bean creates kafkaconsumer which is used in @postconstruct by executor service.    In other use case I need to read the latest offset or replay from specific offset, while i try to create a new kafka cosumer it is throwing `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.consumer`

Is there any to use the existing kafkaConsumer bean to get the latest offset or replay some of the offset.

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
@EnableConfigurationProperties(KafkaProperties.class)
public class KafkaConsumerClientConfig {
    @Bean
    public KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaClientConfig() {
    KafkaConsumer<String, String> kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(MetadataServiceUtil.getConsumerProperties(kafkaProperties));
    log.info("Kafka Consumer created successfully with SecurityProtocol={}", kafkaProperties.getSecurityProtocol());
    kafkaConsumer.subscribe(List.of(kafkaProperties.getTopicName()));
    return kafkaConsumer;
    }
}
```

Kafka client code to create kafka consumer

```
@Component
@Slf4j
@Data
public class PipelineKafkaClient {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
  
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    void startup() {
        log.info("*******Starting event listener********");
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(new EventConsumer(kafkaConsumer));
        // In the EventConsumer i have the code as below
        /*  while(true) {
         *   ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
         *   processBatch(records);
         *   kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
         * }
         */

    }

    public void replayFromSpecificOffset(long offsetToReadFrom, long offsetReadTo) {
        log.info("Replaying messages");
        Properties properties = MetadataServiceUtil.getConsumerProperties(kafkaProperties);
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        // CODE to read from specific offset    
    }

}@Component
@Slf4j
@Data
public class PipelineKafkaClient {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConsumer kafkaConsumer;
  
    @Autowired
    private KafkaProperties kafkaProperties;

    @PostConstruct
    void startup() {
        log.info("*******Starting event listener********");
        executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        executorService.submit(new EventConsumer(kafkaConsumer));
        // In the EventConsumer i have the code as below
        /*  while(true) {
         *   ConsumerRecords<String, String> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(500));
         *   processBatch(records);
         *   kafkaConsumer.commitSync();
         * }
         */

    }

    public void replayFromSpecificOffset(long offsetToReadFrom, long offsetReadTo) {
        log.info("Replaying messages");
        Properties properties = MetadataServiceUtil.getConsumerProperties(kafkaProperties);
        KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
        // CODE to read from specific offset    
    }

}
```

Comment: You should use @KafkaListener annotation for this, not manually define a consumer instance

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to create new instance of KC in your function but that bean is already registered in Spring configuration class KafkaConsumerClientConfig. Solution: try to re use the existing KC instance as a bean in config class instead of new one. Inject it in a class where you want to use it. Here is a hint **KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = kafkaConsumer** instead of initiating a new one.

Comment: I tried that already, but i was getting ```java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: KafkaConsumer is not safe for multi-threaded access```